# Loading images: parameter is not valid exception

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I've a problem while drawing image, somtimes it return an exception "invalid parameter". Here's the code:

```
private Image ZoomImage(Image input, Rectangle zoomArea, Rectangle sourceArea)
{
   Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(sourceArea.Width, 
                              sourceArea.Height,  
                              PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

   using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBmp))
   {
      g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
      g.DrawImage(input, sourceArea, zoomArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
      g.Dispose();
   }

   return newBmp;
}
```

I tried to dispose both "g" and "input" object but without success. I noticed that this happens when my image is larger than 900px, maybe it's not related to the code. Any hints?

Comment: side note: `g.Dispose();` is *redundant*, `using` will call it for you

Comment: Exactly what line results in the exception?

Comment: By far the most common reason why you'd get "Invalid parameter" on this code is because your program is running out of memory.  Very common with bitmaps.  Review your code to ensure these bitmaps get properly disposed.  Use a memory profiler.

Comment: Thanks hans, to solve this, I resized the image to lower width & height.